# "Cannot convert string to ImageSource." How can I do this?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mouseevent

```
private void HeroMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Image)sender).Source = GetGlowingImage(((Image)sender).Name);            
    }

    public ImageSource GetGlowingImage(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "Andromeda":
                return "HeroGlowIcons/64px-Andromeda.gif";                
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

I'm just trying to make an event to change the image according to where the mouse entered. But I cannot make this work.

**Edit: I did this in Windows Forms and it work 100% like I want it to. How could I translate something like this in WPF?**

```
void HeroMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).Image = GetGlowingImage(((PictureBox)sender).Name);           
    }


    public Image GetGlowingImage(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "Andromeda":
                return Properties.Resources._64px_Andromedahero___copia;
            case "Engineer":
                return Properties.Resources._64px_Engineerhero___copia;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `GetGlowingImage()` method you need to generate a new `ImageSource`

This link might help: [Setting WPF image source in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350027/setting-wpf-image-source-in-code)

**Edit:**

See the difference here is that in the WindowsForms code you have the Properties.Resources._64px_Andromedahero___copia is the name of an Image variable that contains the image data. In your WPF code the string "filename...." is not an image or image source it's just a string that represents the path to the file. You need to load the image file using that path.

I know it doesn't make sense because at design time you can specify a filename and it builds the ImageSource for you. In code you need to create the ImageSource (or derived object, ie: BitmapSource) and load the appropriate image into it.

**Edit:** Try this, untested (and check my link above):

```
    public ImageSource GetGlowingImage(string name)
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty;

        switch (name)
        {
            case "Andromeda":
                {
                    fileName = "HeroGlowIcons/64px-Andromeda.gif";
                    break;
                }
        }

        BitmapImage glowIcon = new BitmapImage();


        glowIcon.BeginInit();
        glowIcon.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ApplicationName;component/" + fileName);
        glowIcon.EndInit();

        return glowIcon;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not following. I made the new ImageSource inside the method but I still cannot add the string value, so I'm back to square one. :D

Comment: In the code I see about you are returning a string and not a new ImageSource. Did you not include the part of your code that creates the new ImageSource?

return "HeroGlowIcons/64px-Andromeda.gif"; // <- Returning a string

Comment: Um...I tested a code very similar to this in Windows Form. I'm going to edit my question and hopefully my intent will be much clearer. :D

Comment: Unfortunately WindowsForms makes sense and works like you would expect it to. WPF on the other hand does not ;-) Sure with WPF I can make a slick UI but under most circumstances I find I need to jump through hoops just to accomplish something simple.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../../../Images/folder.png", UriKind.Relative));
myBitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
Image.Source = myBitmapImage;
```

Comment: But if I do this, I would be creating a new bitmap and copying it to a new variable. I just want to reference it via a string similar to what I did during layout Image.Source="blablabla", right? Is there a way for my to convert a string to a ImageSource?

Comment: The layout is doing something similiar to this at runtime.

Comment: Papuccino, this is doing the same thing. You're loading the existing image into a BitmapImage. Either way, a C# object has to be created at runtime from a file.

Comment: If his images are in a ResourceDictionary, he can access them by name using FindResource, without needing to instantiate a new BitmapImage.  (Of course WPF will still be instantiating all those images when it loads the resources, but that's a one-off cost -- doesn't have to be paid each time he switches.)

Answer (score 3):

Going by your edit, you are happy to have a static set of images in resources.  If that's correct, you can do this:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <BitmapImage x:Key="andromeda64" UriSource="andromeda_64px.jpg" />
</Application.Resources>
```

then load it as:

```
public ImageSource GetGlowingImage(string name)
{
  switch (name)
  {
    case "Andromeda":
      return (ImageSource)FindResource("andromeda64");
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

FindResource requires you to be in code-behind for something in the visual tree (e.g. an event handler).  If this isn't the case, or if you want to be able to load things that aren't in a resource dictionary, see [Cory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904956/cannot-convert-string-to-imagesource-how-can-i-do-this/1904962#1904962).  The advantage of using and reusing resources is that you don't need to create a BitmapImage each time you use it (though in this case the overhead cost of doing so will be insignificant).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to return a `BitmapSource`. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.jpegbitmapencoder.aspx) has an example of how to create a `BitmapSource` from an image file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an EventTrigger to do this completely in XAML instead of messing with magic strings in the code behind.

[This link would help](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

for more if you intent to change the background of a Grid or other Panel that support System.Windows.Media.Brush with a click of a button

```
private void btnBackgroundImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg;)|*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg";
    dlg.Multiselect = false;
    dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        txtBackImageName.Text = dlg.FileName;
        _layoutRoot.Background = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush(GetImageSource(dlg.FileName));
    }
}


public ImageSource GetImageSource(string filename)
{
    string _fileName = filename;

    BitmapImage glowIcon = new BitmapImage();

    glowIcon.BeginInit();
    glowIcon.UriSource = new Uri(_fileName);
    glowIcon.EndInit();

    return glowIcon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var converter = new Xamarin.Forms.ImageSourceConverter();
var imgSource = (Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource) converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(item.Poster);
```

Comment: It would be great to add some description to your code, so other users can understand it.