# WPF Custom Control: TemplateBinding to Image

Tags: wpf, image, wpf-controls, controltemplate, templatebinding

I am creating a WPF custom control, a `Button` with an `Image` and `Text`. I have added two dependency properties to the control, `ImagePath` and `Text`, and the control template (in Themes\Generic.xaml) is a simple stack panel that arranges the image and text horizontally.

The `Text` property works fine. But for some reason, the sample image in my test project doesn't appear when I use `TemplateBinding` to the `ImagePath` dependency property to get its path. I have tested the image by temporarily replacing the `TemplateBinding` in the custom control with a path to the image, in which case it appears.

I am hoping that someone with more experience in this area can take a look and tell me why the control isn't working as expected. Thanks for your help.

My VS 2008 solution contains one project, CustomControlDemo. The project contains a custom control, TaskButton.cs, and a main window, Window1.xaml, that I use to test the control. My test image, calendar.png, is located in a Resources folder at the root level of the project, and Generic.xaml is located in a Themes folder, also at the root level of the project.

Here is the code for my custom control (from TaskButton.cs):

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CustomControlDemo
{
    public class TaskButton : RadioButton
    {
        #region Fields

        // Dependency property backing variables
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagePathProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor.
        /// </summary>
        static TaskButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TaskButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TaskButton)));

            // Initialize ImagePath dependency properties
            ImagePathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImagePath", typeof(string), typeof(TaskButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
            TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TaskButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        }

        #endregion

        #region Dependency Property Wrappers

        /// <summary>
        /// The ImagePath dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public string ImagePath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImagePathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImagePathProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Text dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And here is the control template (from Generic.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlDemo">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TaskButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TaskButton}">
                    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImagePath}"  Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="{DynamicResource TaskButtonTextBrush}" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And finally, here is the Window1 markup that I am using to test the control:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomControlDemo.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:CustomControlDemo"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <customControl:TaskButton ImagePath="Resources\calendar.png" Text="Calendar" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any ideas why the image path isn't working? Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image doesn't take a string as a source :) You can see this in intellisense. You need to bind on an ImageSource (Or use an IValueConverter to convert the string to an ImageSource)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904956/cannot-convert-string-to-imagesource-how-can-i-do-this) question for some tips on how to do this conversion.

Answer (score 11):

I am going to leave cwap's answer as the accepted answer, because it is technically correct. However, it turns out that there is an easier way to solve this problem.

TemplateBindings aren't first-class Binding objects. They are designed to be lightweight, so they are one-way, and they lack some features of other Binding objects. Most notably, they don't support known type converters associated with a target. See MacDonald, **Pro WPF in C# 2008**, p. 872. That's why cwap responds correctly that I would probably need to create a type converter and reference it specifically in the control template for my custom button.

But I don't have to use a TemplateBinding to bind the control template to the ImagePath property of my custom control. I can use a plain old Binding object. Here is the revised markup for my custom control's template:

```
<!-- Task Button Default Control Template-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TaskButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TaskButton}">
                <StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="5,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you look at the ImageControl in the template, you can see the change. Note the RelativeSource property in the same object. Setting this property to ={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} is what lets me enter a relative path in my Window1 instance of the TaskButton and have it resolved correctly in the custom control.

So my recommendation for others researching this thread would be to skip the value converter and simply switch from TemplateBinding to Binding for the Image property.

Thanks also to Marco Zhou, who provided [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/edec50f6-d1c7-4891-a814-a9c6f154baf9/) to a similar question in the MSDN WPF forum.

Answer (score 2):

Actually neither of these answers are correct.

`{TemplateBinding ImagePath}` is nothing more than a shortcut for `{Binding Path=ImagePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` and as such is almost completely identical.

Also if you provide a string for `ImagePath` it will correctly resolve to an `ImageSource` although you take a hit in application performance. The real issue has to do with relative and absolute image path on the supplied `ImagePath="Resources\calendar.png"` in the xaml for the test. This clues the compiler to think that the supplied path is absolute because of the use of \ instead of / in defining the path.

The reason that the long form of the binding works and the shortcut doesn't is that it provides clues to the compiler that the source of the image supplied (Resources\calendar.png) is a relative path not an absolute path, therefore the image is found and the binding works. If you debug the binding you will see that the shortcut tries resolve the supplied string into an image source but can not find the file "Resources\calendar.png" If you provide a full URI to the image i.e `"C:\...\Resources\calendar.png"` or the corresponding blend notation of `"/application;component/Resources/calendar.png"` then the image will be found and the binding resolved.

This point becomes really important when you are trying to reference images from an external source instead of those compiled as resources into the final compilation.

Answer (score 0):

simple way(tested)
1-make your valueConverter like this

```
  public class objectToImageSourceConverter:IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            string packUri =value.ToString();
            ImageSource Source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(packUri) as ImageSource;
            return Source;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

2-bind your Image Source to parent's string properety (i used "tag" property)
like this xaml:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Height="Auto" Margin="0,11.75,5.5,10.75" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="40.997" Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```