# How to create custom button from custom control?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I'm testing some codes about custom control. I had the following styles defines in Themes folder.`LayerGrid.xaml`.A `button` with an `image` and `text`.  This `PanelButtonStyle`style is used in `layergrid.cs`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type common:LayerGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True"
                           Name="PART_ParentPanel">
                    <DockPanel.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="PanelButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Border x:Name="BorderPath" Margin="0"
                                            BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource TabItemBackgroundBrushUnselected}"
                                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem_BorderBrush_Selected}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image Source="/MCLF;component/Images/图像 3.png" Width="15" Height="15"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center " VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                        Text ="{TemplateBinding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DockPanel.Resources>
                    <StackPanel Name="PART_BottomCntl" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="AliceBlue"></StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="PART_LeftCntl" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="AliceBlue">
                        <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="PART_RightCntl" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="AliceBlue">
                        <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Grid Name="PART_MasterGrid" IsSharedSizeScope="True" Background="AliceBlue"></Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


private Button AddToColumnStackPanel(Layer layer)
{
    var btn = new Button
    {
        //Background = Brushes.Transparent,
        //BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent,
        //BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
        //Height = 22,
        //MinWidth = 55.0,
        Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
        //FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
        Style = (Style)PART_MasterGrid.FindResource("PanelButtonStyle"),
    };
    btn.Click += (o, e) =>...
}
```

And the `DP Layer.Name` is determined in `MainWindow.xaml` with

```
<controls:Layer Level="1" Orientation="Column" Name="Symbols" ColumnLocation="Left">
<controls:Layer.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <vm:MainViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
    </Grid>
</controls:Layer.Content>
```

Now the problem is the `DP Name=Symbols` is not bind correctly into the button `PanelButtonStyle`
I read a similar post but that example set the whole target type to the `DP somecustomControl`[WPF Custom Control: TemplateBinding to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935919/wpf-custom-control-templatebinding-to-image)

[image]

**Update**: The `DP Name` is in `class Layer`,which is used to define the properties of each layer's location, orientation, name, content etc... The `class LayerGrid` serves as the class backing the custom control.
In `LayerGrid.cs` we have:

```
public class LayerGrid : ContentControl
{
    ...
}
public class Layer : UIElement
{
    public enum LayerOrientation
    {
        Row,
        Column
    }

    public enum LayerColumnLocation
    {
        Left,
        Right
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LevelProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnLocationProperty;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }
    static Layer()
    {
        NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                    "Name",
                                                    typeof(string),
                                                    typeof(Layer));
        ...
    }
}
```

And `LayerGrid.xaml` serves the purpose of laying out the general panels; Each button will be added to the corresponding stackPanel such as `PART_LeftCntl` by calling the function above.

```
<DockPanel>
<StackPanel Name="PART_BottomCntl" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="AliceBlue"></StackPanel>
<StackPanel Name="PART_LeftCntl" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="AliceBlue">
    <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Name="PART_RightCntl" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="AliceBlue">
    <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
</StackPanel>
<Grid Name="PART_MasterGrid" IsSharedSizeScope="True" Background="AliceBlue"></Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

And `MainWindow.xaml` is responsible for giving the contents inside;

**Update2** Below an example of the same `style` is attached.Only Button`style` is changed.https://www.dropbox.com/sh/os34tr8zl21uj4o/AAC_segoCWzAbJMFzCKHyZnpa?dl=0

```
//var btn = new Button
    //{
    //    Background = Brushes.Transparent,
    //    BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent,
    //    BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
    //    Height = 22,
    //    MinWidth = 65.0,
    //    Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 15, 0),
    //    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    //    Style = (Style)PART_MasterGrid.FindResource("buttonStyle"),
    //    Content = layer.Name
    //};
    var btn = new Button
    {

        Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
        //FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
        Style = (Style)PART_MasterGrid.FindResource("PanelButtonStyle")
        //Content = layer.Name
    };
```

Comment: I thought the solution should be just delete `Content` in code behind and make the binding to be`templatebinding Name` which is a DP; so that i do not need to concern it anymore.

Comment: Are you pointing to `{TemplateBinding Name}`? If yes, then try to change it to `{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` or `{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=common:LayerGrid}}`. If this is not what you are looking for, could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @pushpraj I tried the codes above but the `DP Name` is not shown to be binded. I also tried `Text ="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=common:Layer}}` as `DP Name` is actually in `class Layer`

Comment: could you provide the details of where the button is placed and where is the layer?

Comment: @pushpraj The button is added to a stackPanel `PART_LeftCntl` which is defined as part of the custom control by calling `AddToColumnStackPanel`;And the binding source `Name`is defined in `MainWindow.xaml`.

Comment: From what I can see the `TemplatedParent`, `FindAncestor` or the approach provided in the answer should help. Sorry to trouble you again, but is it possible for you to provide a working sample?

Comment: @pushpraj It's my fault.. I attached an example using the styles. You can uncomment the `btn` part to see the effects before changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for how to create the binding in code behind.

So this should work for you

```
Binding b = new Binding("Name");
b.Source = layer;
btn.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, b);
```

so remove `Content = layer.Name` & add this code before `btn.Click += (o, e) =>...`

give it a try and see if this is what you are looking for

---

**EDIT**

After looking at your implementation I found that the buttons are directly added to parts (StackPanel) of the layered grid template instead of layer (see below). So Relative source may not help here.

[image: tree]

However, there are ways how you can achieve your goal in this scenario. As an easy option you can leverage Content property of Button.

So start by binding the Text property it to the template's Content property

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="10"
           Text ="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
```

then in the code you can simply use `Content = layer.Name` if the Name is not supposed to change.

eg

```
var btn = new Button
{
    Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
    Style = (Style)PART_MasterGrid.FindResource("PanelButtonStyle"),
    Content = layer.Name
};
```

Or alternatively you can bind Name with Content property to reflect the changes if needed.

eg

```
var btn = new Button
{
    Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
    Style = (Style)PART_MasterGrid.FindResource("PanelButtonStyle")
};

Binding b = new Binding("Name");
b.Source = layer;
btn.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, b);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I just made my question more clear. The original button is just a text so only `btn.Content= somestring` is needed.