# How to set image content to ContentControl dynamically using style?

Tags: wpf

I have custom `Button` which contains `ContentControl` named "IconBox", which content depends on triggers:

```
<Button> 
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                         <Grid>
                          <!-- somethig here ..... -->
                          <ContentControl x:Name="IconBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                           <!-- triggers here -->
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<!-- closing tags ... -->
</Button>
```

Most of the triggers looks like:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Flag}" Value="icon1">
 <Setter TargetName="IconBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
 <Setter TargetName="IconBox" Property="Style" 
  Value="{DynamicResource icon1}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Where icon1 is a `ControlTemplate` with `ViewBox` and vector images inside.
So it's already known.

Now I need to add also bitmap images, which name contains in new Model's property let's call it `Image`.

So I want something like:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Flag}" Value="useImage">
 <Setter TargetName="IconBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
 <Setter TargetName="IconBox" Property="Style" 
  Value="{DynamicResource ImageTemplate}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

How then `ImageTemplate` should look like?

I've tried next one:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="ImageTemplate">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" 
                                         Converter="{StaticResource ImagePathConverter}" 
                                         Path="Image"/>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But it didn't work. Why?

`Image` contains sting like "image1.bmp", and `ImagePathConverter` simply adds full path to it - "%CurrentDir%\Resources\image1.bmp"

Breakpoint inside converter doesn't hit. As far as one inside `Image` getter.
And I have no idea why. Maybe some error happens inside my template or trigger?

The other triggers with `Canvas` inside `ViewBox` works fine.

Though when I'm using VisualTree to check this element properties in runtime, breakpoint inside `Image` getter hits.

Any other ideas how could I implement the image inside ImageBox?

Comment: Is the Image property defined in the same class as the Flag property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
    <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ImagePathConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

...you could set the `ContentTemplate` of the `ContentControl` to this one:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Flag}" Value="useImage">
    <Setter TargetName="IconBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter TargetName="IconBox" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ImageTemplate}"/>
    <Setter TargetName="IconBox" Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

The `Content` property should be bound to the object where the `Image` property is defined.

Also note that your converter should return an `ImageSource` and not a `string`:

["Cannot convert string to ImageSource." How can I do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904956/cannot-convert-string-to-imagesource-how-can-i-do-this)