# How to change image source on runtime?

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage

I get new bitmap from some other component ( dont have any control on the other component ) every 5 seconds and i need to update my wpf image control with the new bitmap ( every 5 seconds ... ).

I cant find any way to update this wpf image control in run-time.

How can i do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is seriously short on details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a another question like this 
[Setting WPF image source in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350027/setting-wpf-image-source-in-code)

the answer boils down to

```
ImgOnForm.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/yourApp;component/img.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me :

```
chemin = "/Assets/Images/" + nomFichier + ".gif";
MonImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(base.BaseUri, chemin));
```

None of the suggestions I found on the forums worked (I had no image, or an ArgumentException). But with "base.BaseUri" as first agument, it worked at last.