# How does WPF reference images added as an image resource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I have a WPF application where I added the images as resources to the project (not from project settings, like how the 2nd answer does it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350027/setting-wpf-image-source-in-code)), so they are under a folder. I use them like this in xaml:

```
<Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="/Images/Effect.png" />
```

When I build this app, only the dependent dlls and the app itself is put into the `Debug/Release` folder. The Icons that reside inside the project and the actual folders and files are inside the project's folder. Those aren't copied into `Debug/Release`.

I am able to run this application from anywhere, and the images work, so it must be turning the relative paths to hard coded paths?

If that's the case, how am I gonna be able to distribute those Image files to other machines?

I want to be able to always have the Images relative to the app, both in reference and on disk.

Is this the best way or is there a better way? In the end, I want to easily distribute these images and the app to other machines.

Comment: Aren't the images compiled right into the binary?

Comment: It does? How can I verify this? You might be right though, I renamed the Images folder and the application still worked. But if the images are compiled into the exe, then why am I getting this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807310/images-in-a-wpf-window-throw-exception-when-launched-via-reflection/5807363

Answer (score 3):

The images are getting compiled into the assemblies as resources. They are not referenced from their original location on your disk.

When you specify your `Image.Source` like that, WPF looks for the appropriate image in the current assembly. You can also reference images (as well as other resources) that reside in referenced assemblies. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) is some detailed explanation about the resource URI format in WPF (called "Pack URI").