# How to programmatically set the Image source

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, code-behind

When the Image's Source property is set the following way, the picture is taken from `/Images/down.png`.

How would I do the same thing programmatically?

```
<Image x:Name="myImg" Source="/MyProject;component/Images/down.png" />
```

The following would not work, since Image.Source property is not of a string type.

```
myImg.Source = "/MyProject;component/Images/down.png";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350027/setting-wpf-image-source-in-code

Comment: While Silverlight and WPF are similar in many ways, I wouldn't say this is a duplicate. Especially when it comes to resource location.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try this:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyProject;component/Images/down.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Oh, so basically, it is the Uri class that does the conversion, depending on what is specified in a string. Didn't know that.

Comment: Then:
myImg.Source = image;

If you specify an absolute path, remember to set it to UriKind.Absolute.

Answer (score 17):

```
myImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"component/Images/down.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Don't forget to set Build Action to "Content", and Copy to output directory to "Always".

Answer (score 7):

Try to assign the image that way instead:

```
imgFavorito.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(base.BaseUri, @"/Assets/favorited.png"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{yourImageName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LOGO.png"));}
```

LOGO refers to your image

Hoping to help anyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pictureBox",
            Size = new Size(100, 50),
            Location = new Point(14, 17),
            Image = Image.FromFile(@"c:\Images\test.jpg"),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        };
p.Controls.Add(picture);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use asp:image

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"
           AlternateText="Image text"
           ImageAlign="left"
           ImageUrl="images/image1.jpg"/>
```

and codebehind to change image url

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "/MyProject;component/Images/down.png";
```

Comment: Note that the tag for the question says Silverlight. I am not doing anything in ASP. But thanks for the reply, anyway.