# Use MVVM Light EventToCommand on a cefSharp event

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, cefsharp

I've some issues:

I've a web browser from `cefSharp` on which I'm trying to trigger a command on load:

My command is currently empty:

```
        LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {

        });
```

The issue is that when the event is triggered, before even entering in my command, I get an `InvalidOperationException` about a cross thread exception.

For what I see [here](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/E_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_FrameLoadEnd.htm) it seems that this event is triggered from a thread that is not the UI thread.

I've the feeling that the `EventToCommand` class tries to get some UI stuff which cause the application to crash.

How would you address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using a `Behaviour`.

```
public class ChromiumLoadedBehaviour : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser>
{
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Command.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ChromiumLoadedBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Command?.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

If you dont know - how to use the `Behaviour` - check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316451/wpf-image-fallback-doesnt-work-on-failed-web-images/44317084#44317084)

**Additional information**

Maybe use the `FrameLoadEnd` event.