# Changing source of image element

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I try to change picture of `image1`. In collection I have "1.png" and "2.png".

In properties of `image1` the `Source` is "/Appname;component/pictures/1.png"

I wrote:

```
image1.Source = "/Appname;component/pictures/2.png";
```

but it doesn't work, of course, because "implicit conversion from string to System.Windows.Media.ImageSource is not possible".

How to change the picture in `image1` to "2.png"?

Comment: Have you looked at this question and answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350027/setting-wpf-image-source-in-code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly assign a `string` as image source. But you can use a `BitmapImage` as source.

Example:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Appname;component/pictures/2.png", UriKind.Relative));
image1.Source = bitmap;
```

If this doesn't work then something is wrong with your `Uri` (image path) and you should have a look at the link provided by Zannjaminderson (in the comments).