# how to get to Grid x:Name="ControlPanelGrid"

Tags: silverlight, xaml, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I have the following xaml and I am trying to get to the Grid to make it invisible at some point in my code if the code reaches there. Being new to .net and silverlight and xaml I am not sure why my code behind doesn't find Grid Controlpanel

please see my xaml code here

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:smf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core;assembly=Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core" xmlns:smfm="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media;assembly=Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core" xmlns:plugins3d="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives.S3D;assembly=Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins" xmlns:Microsoft_SilverlightMediaFramework_Utilities_Offline="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Utilities.Offline;assembly=Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Utilities" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:smf_util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/smf/2010/xaml/converters" xmlns:smf_accesscontrols="http://schemas.microsoft.com/smf/2010/xaml/accesscontrols" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" xmlns:ec="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/controls"    
    x:Class="SPlayer.MainPage"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>

            ................
            ................

            <Style x:Key="SMFPlayerStyle1" TargetType="smf:SMFPlayer">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                .......
                ......
                            <Grid x:Name="ControlPanelGrid" Margin="8,-26,8,13" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Opacity="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="ControlPanel" Margin="2,3,3,5" Stroke="#FF474747" RadiusY="4" RadiusX="4" Opacity="0.9" StrokeThickness="0.5">
                                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.26" BlurRadius="7" Direction="319"/>
                                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF191919" Offset="0.936"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF454545" Offset="0.187"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF191919"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Grid x:Name="timelinecontrols" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="0,0,165,13" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" d:IsHidden="True">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <smf:Timeline x:Name="TimelineElement" Cursor="Hand" Chapters="{TemplateBinding Chapters}" EndPosition="{TemplateBinding EndPosition}" Foreground="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsLive="{TemplateBinding IsMediaLive}" LivePosition="{TemplateBinding LivePosition}" Margin="80,0,170,-10" StartPosition="{TemplateBinding StartPosition}" TimelineMarkers="{TemplateBinding TimelineMarkers}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TimelineStyle1}" />
                                    <Border x:Name="TimeContainer" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Opacity="0">
                                        <Grid Height="28" MaxHeight="28" MinWidth="60" MinHeight="28" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.367*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.383*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="CurrentPositionElement" Foreground="#FFC1C1C1" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="8,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding PlaybackPosition, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanValueConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="TimeSeparatorElement" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#FFFDFAFA" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0" Opacity="0.4" Text="|" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="CurrentDurationElement" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="#FFFDFDFD" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0.4" Padding="0,0,8,0" Text="{Binding EndPosition, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanValueConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="btnVloume" Margin="0,-1,383,5" Source="volume.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="49" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, GridBox" Width="53" HorizontalAlignment="Right" d:IsHidden="True"/>
                                <smf:VolumeControl x:Name="VolumeElement" VolumeLevel=".5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,-46.5,326.074,-50.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="36" Style="{StaticResource VolumeControlStyle1}" d:IsHidden="True" >
                                    <smf:VolumeControl.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="90.02"/>
                                    </smf:VolumeControl.RenderTransform>
                                </smf:VolumeControl>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="FullScreenToggleElement" BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="28" Margin="0,14,153,11" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource FullScreenElementStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="29" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Image x:Name="_3D" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,1,180,3" Source="3D.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="53" Height="49"  Cursor="Hand" Opacity="0.8" MouseLeftButtonUp="_3D_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction x:Name="_3d_100_Opacity" PropertyName="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction x:Name="_3d_80_Opacity" PropertyName="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </Image>
                                <Image x:Name="analytics" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="980,3,0,-1" Source="analytics.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="53"  Cursor="Hand" Opacity="0.7">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction x:Name="analytics_MouseEnter" PropertyName="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction x:Name="analytics_MouseLeave" PropertyName="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </Image>
                                <Image x:Name="btn_fullscreen" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,140,4" Source="full_screen.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="53" Height="49" Opacity="0.8" Cursor="Hand">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction x:Name="btn_fullscreen_mouseOver" PropertyName="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction x:Name="btn_fullscreen_mouseOut" PropertyName="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </Image>
                                <smf:PlayElement x:Name="PlayElement" Content="PlayElement" PlayState="{TemplateBinding PlayState}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Margin="9,2,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PlayElementStyle1}" Width="53" Cursor="Hand" />
                                <Image Margin="0,4,5,8" Source="logo.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="96"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid x:Name="ControllerContainer" Height="40" Grid.Row="4" Visibility="{Binding IsControlStripVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Opacity="0">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.481481,1" StartPoint="0.481481,0.00636957">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF78808B" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF58606A" Offset="0.287958"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF38424E" Offset="0.680628"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF333D49" Offset="0.984293"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid x:Name="playercontrols" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="19,0,16,0" Opacity="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Button x:Name="ReplayElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ReplayButtonStyle}" Width="36"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="RewindElement" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource RWButtonStyle}" Width="36">
                                        <Button.BorderBrush>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Button.BorderBrush>
                                    </Button>
                                    <smf:PlayElement Cursor="Hand" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" PlayState="{TemplateBinding PlayState}" Width="60"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="FastForwardElement" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource FFButtonStyle}" Width="36"/>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="SlowMotionElement" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource SlowMotionButtonStyle}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Slow Motion" Width="36"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="divider1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="2">
                                    <Path Data="M245.16667,0 L245.16667,39.109009" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="1">
                                        <Path.Stroke>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.509"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF343E4A" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF757D87" Offset="0"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Path.Stroke>
                                    </Path>
                                    <Path Data="M245.16667,0 L245.16667,39.109009" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="1">
                                        <Path.Stroke>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFDFEFF" Offset="0.509"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF36404C" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF757D87" Offset="0"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Path.Stroke>
                                    </Path>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="divider2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="2" Opacity="0">
                                    <Path Data="M245.16667,0 L245.16667,39.109009" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="1">
                                        <Path.Stroke>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.509"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF343E4A" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF757D87" Offset="0"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Path.Stroke>
                                    </Path>
                                    <Path Data="M245.16667,0 L245.16667,39.109009" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="1">
                                        <Path.Stroke>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFDFEFF" Offset="0.509"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF343E4A" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF757D87" Offset="0.009"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Path.Stroke>
                                    </Path>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="functioncontrols" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="4" Margin="16,0" Opacity="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="CaptionToggleElement" Cursor="Hand" Content="CC" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource CaptionDisplayToggleButtonStyle}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Closed Captions" Width="36" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox"/>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="GraphToggleElement" Cursor="Hand" Content="G" Grid.Column="1" Height="28" Style="{StaticResource PlayerGraphButtonStyle}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Toggle Graph" Width="36"/>
                                    <ComboBox x:Name="AudioStreamSelectionElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource btnBaseGradient}" Background="Black" Cursor="Hand" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="3" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding AvailableAudioStreams}" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource AudioStreamMenu}" SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedAudioStream}" Width="110">
                                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource iconGradient}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="divider3" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0" Width="2" Opacity="0">
                                    <Path Data="M245.16667,0 L245.16667,39.109009" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="1">
                                        <Path.Stroke>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.509"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF343E4A" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF757D87" Offset="0"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Path.Stroke>
                                    </Path>
                                    <Path Data="M245.16667,0 L245.16667,39.109009" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="1">
                                        <Path.Stroke>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFDFEFF" Offset="0.509"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF343E4A" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF757D87" Offset="0"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Path.Stroke>
                                    </Path>
                                </Grid>
                                <smf:BitrateMonitor x:Name="BitrateMonitorElement" Grid.Column="6" HighDefinitionBitrate="{TemplateBinding HighDefinitionBitrate}" Height="40" Margin="5,0,7,0" MaximumPlaybackBitrate="{TemplateBinding MaximumPlaybackBitrate}" PlaybackBitrate="{TemplateBinding PlaybackBitrate}" Width="36" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>


      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <smf:SMFPlayer x:Name="smfPlayer"  Style="{StaticResource SMFPlayerStyle1}" PlaylistVisibility="Disabled"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

here is my code behind file

```
namespace SPlayer
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        .........

        public MainPage(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
......
```

as you can see my namespace is correct in xaml but I still cant access the grid `<Grid x:Name="ControlPanelGrid" Margin="8,-26,8,13" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Opacity="0">`

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C# code you can use the `FindChild<T>` found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)

It would look something like:

```
Grid controlPanelGrid = UIHelper.FindChild<Grid>(smfPlayer, "ControlPanelGrid");
```

Comment: It says UIHelper does not exist in this contezxt

Comment: Replace UIHelper with whatever class name you put FindChild<T> in. Just to be sure: you did copy the FindChild<T> method from the link?

Answer (score -1):

For clarification: your Grid `ControlPanelGrid` is a child of `SMFPlayerStyle1` in the resources of your `UserControl`?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="SMFPlayerStyle1" TargetType="smf:SMFPlayer">
     [...]
     <Grid x:Name="ControlPanelGrid" Margin="8,-26,8,13" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Opacity="0">
     [...]
     </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

To access this element programatically, you need to dive down the object graph starting with `SMFPlayerStyle1...`. Depending on structure of the `SMFPlayer` object you may be able to access it through a property of this.