# How do I reference a root directory in my WPF App?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, uri, filepath

I'm instancing a `Uri` to be used as an image source but the string (file path) I'm providing is invalid. I understand why - it's because I'm using a relative path:

```
"Resources/Images/" + draggedAct.Category.ToLower() + ".png"
```

When I had this problem in `asp .net` I used `Server.MapPath(imageString)` to resolve the full path but I don't know the equivalent in WPF.

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Comment: Have you tried using "~/Resources/Images/"? It's another way of doing it that works in asp.net, not sure if it works in WPF though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the pack uri syntax (see msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
"pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/"+ draggedAct.Category.ToLower() +".png"

// Absolute URI (default)
Uri absoluteUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/"+ draggedAct.Category.ToLower() +".png", UriKind.Absolute);
```

or:

```
// Relative URI
Uri relativeUri = new Uri("/Resources/Images/"+ draggedAct.Category.ToLower() +".png", UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pack URI, as described in the answer to this StackOverflow Question: [Setting WPF image source in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350027/setting-wpf-image-source-in-code)