# Cannot set image source in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

There are numerous questions and answers regarding setting image source in code behind, such as this [Setting WPF image source in code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350027/setting-wpf-image-source-in-code)

I have followed all these steps and yet not able to set an image. I code in WPF C# in VS2010. I have all my image files under a folder named "**Images**" and all the image files are set to **Copy always**. And **Build Action** is set to **Resource**, as instructed from documentation.

My code is as follow. I set a **dog.png** in XAML and change it to **cat.png** in code behind.

```
// my XAML
<Image x:Name="imgAnimal" Source="Images/dog.png" />

// my C#
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/FooApplication;component/Images/cat.png");
imgAnimal.Source = img;
```

Then I get a empty, blank image of emptiness. I do not understand why .NET makes setting an image so complicated..w

**[EDIT]**

So the following works

```
imgAnimal.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/FooApplication;component/Images/cat.png"));
```

It works, but I do not see any difference between the two code. Why the earlier doesn't work and the latter does? To me they are the same..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try following:

```
imgAnimal.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/FooApplication;component/Images/cat.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Default *UriKind* is *Absolute*, you should rather use *Relative* one.

**[EDIT]**

Use *BeginInit* and *EndInit*:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
img.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/FooApplication;component/Images/cat.png");
img.EndInit();
imgAnimal.Source = img;
```