# Add an image in a WPF button

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button

I tried this solution:

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Pictures/img.jpg" />
        <TextBlock>Blablabla</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

But I can see the image only in the project window, and when I launch the program it disappears.

If I try this:

```
  Image img = new Image();
  img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("foo.png"));

  StackPanel stackPnl = new StackPanel();
  stackPnl.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
  stackPnl.Margin = new Thickness(10);
  stackPnl.Children.Add(img);

  Button btn = new Button();
  btn.Content = stackPnl;
```

I get a "'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll" exception.

What is the solution?

Comment: Is your image defined as 'Resource' in it's properties? (right click  it -> properties -> Build Action='Resource')

Comment: Thanks! You put me in the right direction: I drag and dropped the Image in Solution Explorer and now I can see it :)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In the case of a 'missing' image there are several things to consider:

1. When XAML can't locate a resource it might ignore it (when it won't throw a `XamlParseException`)
2. The resource must be properly added and defined:

   - **Make sure it exists in your project where expected.**
   - **Make sure it is built with your project as a resource.**

     *(Right click → Properties → BuildAction='Resource')*

[image: Snippet]

Another thing to try in similar cases, which is also useful for reusing of the image (or any other resource):

**Define your image as a resource in your XAML:**

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
     <Image x:Key="MyImage" Source.../>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And later use it in your desired control(s):

```xml
<Button Content="{StaticResource MyImage}" />
```

Comment: I think you will have to put double quotes like <Button Content="{StaticResource MyImage}" />  rather than    content={...}.

Comment: the source path can try <Image x:Key="kkk" Source="../Folder1/Img.png"/>

Comment: I tried your second method but stuck with the this error. "The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'UserControl'."

Answer (score 35):

Please try the below XAML snippet:

```
<Button Width="300" Height="50">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="Pictures/img.jpg" Width="20" Height="20"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Blablabla" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

In XAML elements are in a tree structure. So you have to add the child control to its parent control. The below code snippet also works fine. Give a name for your XAML root grid as 'MainGrid'.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"foo.png"));

StackPanel stackPnl = new StackPanel();
stackPnl.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
stackPnl.Margin = new Thickness(10);
stackPnl.Children.Add(img);

Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = stackPnl;
MainGrid.Children.Add(btn);
```

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
<Button Height="100" Width="100">
  <StackPanel>
    <Image Source="img.jpg" />
    <TextBlock Text="Blabla" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

It should work. But remember that you must have an image added to the resource on your project!

Answer (score 9):

You can set the button's background to the image if you then want to overlay text.

```
<Button>
   <Button.Background>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="/AssemblyName;component/Pictures/img.jpg"/>
   </Button.Background>
   <TextBlock>Blablabla</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Watch out for the image source syntax. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350027/setting-wpf-image-source-in-code) for help.

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same issue. I've fixed it by using the following code.

```
        <Button Width="30" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Click="OnSearch" >
            <DockPanel>
                <Image Source="../Resources/Back.jpg"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
```

**Note:** Make sure the build action of the image in the property window, should be `Resource`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try ContentTemplate:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20"
        Template="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="../Folder1/Img1.png" Width="20" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Comment: what should I fill for sometemplate ?

Comment: if you're not using `Template`, you can remove `Template="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}"`, if you want to know what template is, you can try to google `wpf template`

Answer (score 2):

I found that I also had to set the [Access Modifier in the Resources tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4dDL.png) to 'Public' - by default it was set to Internal and my icon only appeared in design mode but not when I ran the application.