# WPF button icon change programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change icon of the following button programmatically

```
<Button x:Name="btnSendInvite" Height="32" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Hand" Margin="1,5" ToolTip="Call" Click="btnSendInvite_Click" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                                <DockPanel>
                                    <DockPanel.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/button.png" />
                                    </DockPanel.Background>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="Resources/dial.png" Height="30" Margin="14,0"></Image>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DockPanel>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
```

Need to change `dial.png` icon to `hangup.png`. How it possible in c#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515631/add-an-image-in-a-wpf-button, you should check this out!

Comment: Create a control template style in Resources then add that control template to Button Template.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to change the image using code, then you should data bind the `Image.Source` property and then change your data bound image path:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="30" Margin="14,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

The default value for your new property would be `Resources/dial.png` and you could change it like so:

```
ImageSource = "Resources/hangup.png";
```

Of course, your `ImageSource` property must notify the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of the change so that the UI can update the `Image`. However, it must be said that using a `Trigger` or `DataTrigger` to change the `Image.Source` in XAML would be a better solution.

Comment: Of course the correct way to do this is to put an enum into your VM then use a converter to convert the enum to an pair of `<Image />` in your binding.