# How to add an image in a WPF button

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to get it done by doing this

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Pictures/img.jpg" />
        <TextBlock>Blablabla</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

But I can only see it in the project window. When I launch the program, it just disappears.

When I try this, I get a "'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll" exception.

```
Image img = new Image{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("foo.png"))
};

StackPanel stackPnl = new StackPanel{
    Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
    Margin = new Thickness(10)
};
stackPnl.Children.Add(img);

Button btn = new Button{
    Content = stackPnl
};
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Put your pic in resource folder.**
And use below code

```
<Button Width="300" Height="50">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="Pictures/yourimage.jpg" Width="20" Height="20"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Sometext" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

You can see other examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515631/add-an-image-in-a-wpf-button)

Comment: The folder in which an image file is located is irrelevant. What matters is the correct Build Action and that the folder name matches the resource Uri.