# WPF Image control doesn't display ImageSource that was added/assigned programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, image

This method below converts an image from an image file-path to an ImageSource. [Solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423017/4484340)

```
 public static ImageSource GetImageSourceFromPath(string path)
 {
     return new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
 }
```

Here is what a path I've tested looks like[image]

This is how the imagesource gets assigned:

```
Image_Control.Source = GetImageSourceFromPath(path);
```

The problem is that the image doesn't show in the WPF image control.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should change `UriKind.Relative` to `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute`. It allows you to set images with absolute or relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static ImageSource GetImageSourceFromPath(string path)
 {
     return new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, **UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute**));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will works fine with the following changes.

```
 public static ImageSource GetImageSourceFromPath(string path)
     {
         return new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
     }

    Image_Control.Source = GetImageSourceFromPath(path);
```

If you are using full path no need to specify the `UriKind`,other wise use `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.